# how can make invisible other buttons after switch case

Tags: android, html

When I click one button I can show my html files. But other buttons are still stand there.
How can I prevent this?

[screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvB0Z.png)

```
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;
Button bn, deneme, denemeiki;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bn);
    deneme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deneme);
    denemeiki= (Button) findViewById(R.id.denemeiki);
    // init webView
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.simpleWebView);
    // displaying content in WebView from html file that stored in assets folder
    bn.setOnClickListener(new Clik());
    deneme.setOnClickListener(new Clik());
    denemeiki.setOnClickListener(new Clik());
}

public class Clik implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.deneme:
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html.html");
                break;
            case R.id.denemeiki:
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/deneme.html");
                break;
            case R.id.bn:
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/denemeiki.html");
                break;

            default:

        }
    }
}
}
```

[strong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFLJ5.png)

Comment: **`yourButton.setVisibilty(GONE)`**

Comment: Wrap your buttons inside a layout and place this layout as second child inside a vertical linearlayout with webview being the first child (with layout_weight = 1).

Comment: could you give me a sample with my button. and where ı will put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited 
Store all the button id's in integer array idsArr.

```
switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.deneme:
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html.html");
            hideButtons(idsArr,R.id.deneme);        
            break;
        case R.id.denemeiki:
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/deneme.html");
            hideButtons(idsArr,R.id.denemeiki);              
            break;
        case R.id.bn:
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/denemeiki.html");
            hideButtons(idsArr,R.id.bn);              
            break;

        default:

    }

    public void hideButtons(int[] idsArr, int id) // id - button to keep visible
    {
       for(int i=0;i<idsArr.length;i++)
       {
          if(id!=idsArr[i]){
             ((Button)findViewById(idsArr[i])).setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }else{
              ((Button)findViewById(idsArr[i])).setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }
       }
    }
```

This will do whatever you have asked but on some action you have to bring back (make hidden buttons visible)the disable buttons.

Comment: thanks but ı have 20 buttons. how can ı add all buttons visibility? is any simple way . ı want to show my html text. than click my back button

Comment: Store all your button ids in integer array and run a loop through array to hide all the buttons with the id's stored in an array